# Nested for loops with if/else in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I just don't get it why when I use this,

```
for(in=1; in<=3;in++) {
    for(out=1; out<=2; out++) {
        console.log('*')
    }
}
```

it prints 6 stars which seems right to me, And when i use it with if/else like this,

```
for(in=0; in<=3; in++) {
    for(out=0; out<=2; out++) {
        if(in == 9) {
            console.log('inside');
        }
    }
    console.log('outside');
}
```

(outside) will be printed 4 times I really don't get it why is it like this ?

Comment: you have `in=0; in<=3; in++` which will loop it 4 times... so `ouside` is printed 4 times....

Comment: It's not in the `if` statement, so why shouldn't it be printed every time?

Comment: Thank you that makes it a little bit clear for me, but what happened now with out=0; out<=2; out++ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`console.log('outside')` is inside the first loop which goes from 0 to 3, so it's printed four times. 'inside' is never printed because `in` never reaches 9

Comment: Your `if` statement does nothing because `in` never reaches `9`. Since there's nothing else inside the inner (`out`) loop, the loop is useless as well.